# Why is there a delay in getting opening trade price using quantmod

Tags: r, quantmod

I'm using quantmod package for my trading but in the last few days I get a delay in getting the open daily price ( SPY ) when I run my code on market open time 9:30 AM EST. After about 10 minutes all is working great and I get the numbers but how can I bypass this delay ? Is it because of my code or another reason?
I use quantmod Version 0.4-4.

```
# rm(list = ls())  # generally considered as bad manner in an MWE
require(quantmod)
options(scipen=999)
spy <- getSymbols(("SPY") , src = 'yahoo', from = '2007-01-01', auto.assign = T)
Warning message:
In download.file(paste(yahoo.URL, "s=", Symbols.name, "&a=", from.m,  :
  downloaded length 168806 != reported length 200
spy<-cbind(SPY)
q <- getQuote("SPY") # adds the current trade row
qCols <- c("Open","High","Low","Last","Volume","Last")
qx <- xts(q[,qCols], as.Date(q[,"Trade Time"]))
SPY <- rbind(SPY, qx)
Warning messages:
  1: In rbind(deparse.level, ...) :
      mismatched types: converting objects to numeric
  2: In rbind(deparse.level, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Comment: Hello @Pascal, Didn't you encounter the delay at all? For me I got the daily open price for SPY after 15 mins from markets open. I'm not sure it's becuase a delay on Yahoo side or from my code.

Comment: No delay. I get it immediately. Maybe some latency. Did you try it now? Also, I get any warning. What is your version of `quantmod`?

Comment: Version is 0.4-4.The delay is only on open time , If I'll run it now it will work fine but on open time it fails to get the daily opening price  for about 10-20 minutes. (it get historical data just fine).

Comment: You have a dev version. It is not clear at what time you run your code. If it runs now, but not earlier or later, I cannot help more.

Comment: Just for clarification: I run the code on market open time 9:30 AM EST

Comment: Maybe you should add this information to your question, as well as the version of `quantmod`. My version is `0.4-5` and I don't get the warnings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a delay because [Yahoo Finance delays their real-time data for most exchanges](http://finance.yahoo.com/exchanges).

Comment: How can I get live data then?