# getSymbols function from quantmod R package not getting correct day opening price during live trading

Tags: r, quantmod

I have an R script that automate my day trading. and I use the getSymbols function to get the opening price for the day of a given stock during live trading. But the number that it gets changes and won't finalize to the right opening price until sometime well after the opening bell.

How do I fix this?

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to provide a definitive answer. My suspicion is that the data in the source database is changing. I would investigate the source data and see if you observe the same thing.

Comment: @imo The only source is yahoo. google no longer provides data

Comment: That is incorrect. `getSymbols` has a number of databases to which it interfaces through the source argument. It would be good to include an example of one your calls to this function and to explain what happens in more detail. You may be interested in the Alpha Vantage source. See `?getSymbols.av`. I still have a suspicion that the issue is at the data source rather than with this function.

Comment: @imo Yes, the default source is Yahoo. From this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995391/why-is-there-a-delay-in-getting-opening-trade-price-using-quantmod, there is a delay in the data from yahoo. So are you saying that there isn't a delay for Alpha Vantage?

Comment: Ah, OK that answers my suspicion in the affirmative. I am not entirely sure about the delay with Alpha Vantage, but it does offer "intra-day" data and looks like it is free to get access. It may be that there is a fee for the more current info. At least worth a look.